# Suddenly can't backup mysql

Tags: mysql

After years of no issues with MySQL backups we are suddenly getting these errors. I can't sort out any way to delete the tables. There shouldn't be any permissions issues. MySQL 5.7.

Error: Couldn't read status information for table civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_2177743371563e34f834c0d9790552b4 ()
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_2177743371563e34f834c0d9790552b4`': Table 'civi.civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_2177743371563e34f834c0d9790552b4' doesn't exist (1146)
Error: Couldn't read status information for table civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_443d27af19bdb52809e75d4b181eab24 ()
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_443d27af19bdb52809e75d4b181eab24`': Table 'civi.civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_443d27af19bdb52809e75d4b181eab24' doesn't exist (1146)
Error: Couldn't read status information for table civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_5fd70ef5bada19f2de97b3c92f38746f ()
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_5fd70ef5bada19f2de97b3c92f38746f`': Table 'civi.civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_5fd70ef5bada19f2de97b3c92f38746f' doesn't exist (1146)
Error: Couldn't read status information for table civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_7ce7ce5c41d286dd8dd07ba9eaa34b75 ()
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_7ce7ce5c41d286dd8dd07ba9eaa34b75`': Table 'civi.civicrm_tmp_e_xggroup_7ce7ce5c41d286dd8dd07ba9eaa34b75' doesn't exist (1146)

Comment: You can try OPTIMIZE TABLE or CHECK TABLE. e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html. You could also try setting your mysqldump to only dump specific tables and exclude these ones, but that doesn't solve it long-term.

Comment: I tried that and mysqlcheck. Everything shows ok, but it's like it doesn't see those bad tables. I can't see them anywhere they just show up as errors if making a dump. I did a dump excluding the bad tables, restored, dumped, ran CiviCRM, dumped again. The first dump worked. The second dump already had tables created and it failed.

Comment: So I managed to get a clean dump file using --ignore-table params for the 700 tmp tables. When I restored to a new database I got the same thing with all the tables hanging around. So then I restored and didn't give the user permission to make temp tables. All seems well running like that. Any issues I'm going to run into later with no temp table permissions?

Comment: Things like contact imports using the UI probably won't work. Some reports need temporary tables. Possibly some scheduled job tasks.